# How can I forward a url to the appropriate page?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, dotnetnuke, friendly-url, forwarding

How can I forward a url such as:

http://www.mysite.com/Join

to the appropriate page:

http://www.mysite.com/JoinOptions/MemberRegistration.aspx

Is there some way to do this?

I'm using a DNN CMS but if you're unfamiliar with DNN and still have a solution for redirecting that would be helpful.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Do you have access to IIS on your server?

Comment: Notice the difference between "redirecting" (typically something involving a 302 status code) and "url rewriting" (typically something that is completely transparent to the user). Which one do you need?

Comment: Yes I have access to IIS. I'm guessing url rewriting... we don't want the user to know that it was a wrong page or anything, just that in our promo video we have "please go to http://www.mysite.com/join to join today" and the page is actually http://www.mysite.com/joinoptions/memberregistration.aspx...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a "friendly URL rule" within DNN.  In the Host Settings page, open the Friendly URL section within the Advanced Settings section.  From there you can add a new rule, that matches `.*/Join/Default.aspx` and replaces it with `~/JoinOptions/MemberRegistration.aspx` (I'm fairly sure that using that style of URL will work, but I *know* that you can replace with a URL like `~/Default.aspx?tabid=423`).

Using this scheme, you need to make sure that IIS lets ASP.NET process the request.  The easiest way to do that is to add a "Join" folder in your file system with a file called Default.aspx.

Comment: Wow - I never thought of doing that

Comment: This only works if that is the first portal on the dnn instance

Answer (score 1):

We once used a DNN module from SnowCovered, you can get it here: http://www.snowcovered.com/Snowcovered2/Default.aspx?tabid=242&PackageID=7262

It's $15 but it will do what you need to without any coding.

You will create a page that is `/Join` and redirect it to `/JoinOptions/MemberRegistration.aspx`

Comment: Note: If you want to have http://yoursite.com/Join (as opposed to Join.aspx) handled by asp.net you'll need to have wildcard mapping set up in IIS for the web site. DNN will handle the extensionless request, but it won't be forwarded to DNN without making the change in IIS first.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache you can create or edit an existing .htaccess file containing:

```
RewriteEngine on
redirect 301 /Join http://www.mysite.com/JoinOptions/MemberRegistration.aspx
```

And place it in your root directory (the directory that http://www.mysite.com/ points to)
It may be useful to read up on Apache [.htaccess files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html) and [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in addition to this.

Edit: Oops. Didn't check the tags.

Comment: Considering the `dotnetnuke` and `asp.net` tags, chances are slim that OP is hosting on Apache ;)

Comment: You can use Managed Fusion URL Rewriter which supports Apache syntax under .NET.  http://urlrewriter.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

Actually without touching IIS and without spending any money  you can do this with a little trickery.

1. Create a folder called JOIN at the root
2. Add a page called default.aspx in that folder
3. add the code below

   ```
   Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

       Dim DomainName As String = Null.NullString
           Dim ServerPath As String
           Dim URL() As String
           Dim intURL As Integer

           ' parse the Request URL into a Domain Name token 
           URL = Split(Request.Url.ToString(), "/")
           For intURL = 2 To URL.GetUpperBound(0)
               Select Case URL(intURL).ToLower
                   Case "admin", "desktopmodules", "mobilemodules", "premiummodules"
                       Exit For
                   Case Else
                       ' check if filename
                       If InStr(1, URL(intURL), ".aspx") = 0 Then
                           DomainName = DomainName & IIf(DomainName <> "", "/", "") & URL(intURL)
                       Else
                           Exit For
                       End If
               End Select
           Next intURL

           ' format the Request.ApplicationPath
           ServerPath = Request.ApplicationPath
           If Mid(ServerPath, Len(ServerPath), 1) <> "/" Then
               ServerPath = ServerPath & "/"
           End If

           DomainName = ServerPath & "JoinOptions/MemberRegistration.aspx"

           Response.Redirect(DomainName,True)

   End Sub
   ```

If you change the Page name you would have to re-edit the file but it works

note:might have to replace the amersan amp with an actual ampersand

Comment: didn't work...I tried replacing all the &amps; with ampersands

Answer (score 0):

If you are on IIS, you can use ISAPI_Rewrite3 tool. The .htaccess for the site will be:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^Join/?$ JoinOptions/MemberRegistration.aspx [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option. Probably a little bit more of a hack than the accepted answer.

**Enable wildcard mapping in IIS**

This allows extensionless URLs to work (e.g. http://yoursite.com/Join)

1. Web site -> right click -> properties
2. Home directory tab -> configuration
3. Mapping tab -> wildcard section -> "insert"
4. Browse to aspnet_isapi.dll (see example path below) -> select file
5. un-check "verify file exists" check box
6. ok ok ok ok until done -> close IIS window

**Create a page in DNN called "Join" and redirect it to the desired page**

Add a page with the name/title Join, set it to not show up in the menu, and set it to 301 redirect to your desired URL (these are all options in the page's settings)

* typically something like C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll