# DotnetNuke redirect

Tags: redirect, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

our client needs to shortcuts to particular pages
We need to redirect non existent urls like

```
http://site.com/promotion1
```

to the actual URL similar to

```
http://site.com/promotions/promotion1/tabid/799/language/en-AU/Default.aspx
```

...

I've sent a list of appropriate DNN modules to our client but it may take them forever to get back to me.
In the mean time they still submitting requests to us to create redirects for them.

if there's no cost involved then i wont have to wait for them to get back to me.

so I'm looking for a **Quick** and **free** way to enable the clients to set these up on this own.

I've looked at:

- [MAS.ActionRedirect](http://www.snowcovered.com/snowcovered2/Default.aspx?tabid=242&PackageID=3302)
- [Ventrian Friendly URL Provider](http://www.ventrian.com/Resources/Projects/FriendlyUrls.aspx)
- [DotNetNuke URL Rewriting HTTP Module](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/aspnet/dnn2url_rewrite.aspx)

But haven't had much luck in the small amount of time i have available.

Has anyone got some suggestions on how to achieve our goal with either the above resources or maybe some additional resource i haven't found yet?

(DNN v4.9)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the built-in friendly URL functionality within DNN, or use a URL rewriter module within IIS.

You can read [my answer about using the DNN Friendly URL functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188065/how-can-i-forward-a-url-to-the-appropriate-page) for more details, or look into the [IIS URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite).

Comment: Friendly urls section is located under host settings which the client can't access, also they would  need permission to create folders in the root directory.

IIS module seems only to be for admins.

the main goal is to enable the client (portal admin) to create these shortcut urls.

Comment: @X-Dev Ah, sorry.  I missed that you want the clients to be able to do this without any host/server access...